# Get List from SharePoint App web

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We have some lists in App web instead of Host Web. These lists are transaction list and we need to save this list as template an d move to some other site.

When I try to save the list as template from app web and getting access denied error message. Please help me how to get the list from app web.

Answer (score 0):

Access Denied error message suggets that you don't have enough permission to do it. I am just speculating but I think you need to grant **full control** permission on the **list** and **web** for the app.

Comment: 've given full control on List and Web in App permission and still facing the same issue. I downloaded the list template from gallery and import stp file into other site collection. When I try to add list app, it does not appear.